# Show that the matrix $AA'$ is symmetric (where A'is the transpose of A).

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the row vectors $a = \begin{bmatrix}a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\\end{bmatrix}$, $b = \begin{bmatrix}b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\\end{bmatrix}$, $c = \begin{bmatrix}c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\\end{bmatrix}$.

(a) Assume that $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^3$ are linearly independent and let $A = 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & x & x^2 \\
        1 & y & y^2 \\
        1 & z & z^2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Show that the matrix $AA'$ is symmetric (where $A'$ is the transpose of $A$).

Comment: This follows from the fact that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$. You don't need the linear independence assumption.

Comment: But can I prove it through linear independence assumption?

Comment: What the symbol $*$ means?

Comment: The linear independence assumption doesn't seem to help us at all, so I don't know why it was given. Have you tried computing $AA^T$ explicitly? Just multiply it out.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be assuming that the rows (or columns) of $A$ are linearly independent because this may not be the case.  The result holds for *all* matrices, not just ones with linearly independent rows.  As littleO suggested, you just have to know that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and $(A^T)^T=A$.  Then you can check that
$$ (AA^T)^T=(A^T)^TA^T=AA^T$$
which exactly says that $AA^T$ is symmetric.